# graphStream or Apache Jena

Tags: java, graph, jena

I need to build a relation graph , and save these relations on disk for future use , I came across those two libraries Apache Jena , GraphStream which would be better ?

Comment: Well it seems you need a GraphDB....why not to consider Neo4J http://www.neo4j.org/ ?

Comment: would be overkill , need a very simple thing

Comment: Well if you need to work with graphs, by seeing Jena and GraphStream, I would suggest the last one (GraphStream); it seems to me that Jean is good for ontologies and RDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing apples (graph libraries) and oranges (RDF libraries). If you want to manipulate graphs whose vertices and edges don't happen to be labeled by URIs (as RDF subjects, predicates, and objects typically are) and whose serializations are not RDF/XML, N-TRIPLE, or N3 (as serializations of RDF graphs typically are)  GraphStream appears to be the rational choice among the two, given the information you have provided.